# How to measure any radius in miles around a given latitude and longitude?

Tags: sql, postgresql, latitude-longitude, radius

I've been struggling for days to create any given radius in miles around a chosen latitude and longitude (latitude = 51.48034773 and longitude = -0.194894315) on PostgreSQL.

The given dataset contains records of millions of coordinates of people's movement patterns. I've tried looking at several different methods but it doesn't work for me on PostgreSQL but I definitely need to do it on PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT device,brand, (
   6380 * acos(
      cos(radians(51.48034773))
      * cos(radians(latitude))
      * cos(radians(lonigtude) - radians(-0.194894315))
      + sin (radians(51.48034773))
      * sin(radians(latitude))
   ))
  AS distance
FROM public.consumer
HAVING distance < 0.5
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

I essentially need to create a radius (for instance 0.5 miles) around a given coordinate (51.48034773, -0.194894315) so I can filter out the rest of the data and only return what people have done within the chosen radius.

Hope that made some sense. Please let me know if you have any questions.

ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, distance
from (
    select device,brand, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.8391) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( lonigtude ) - radians(4.6265) ) + sin( radians(51.8391) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) as distance
    from public.consumer
) as dt
where distance < 0.5;
```

Comment: It returns an error: "ERROR:  function radians(character) does not exist
LINE 17: ...( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.48034773) ) * cos( radians( l.."

Comment: Also hints that: "HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: This error is pretty much the same error it always returns. It seems to have a problem with the "radians" but I've checked for postgreSQL radians is correct. Source: https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/radians-function.php